# set the columns format max in xml generate from table in oracle

Tags: oracle11g

```
SET PAGES 0;
SET LINE 1000;
SET LONG 9999999;
SPOOL C:\pensionnew.xml;
col foo format a60000;
--SELECT DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML('SELECT * FROM DATAAG')foo FROM DUAL;
SELECT DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML('SELECT XMLConcat(XMLElement("ID", e.ID),XMLElement("LAST_OFFICE_WORKED", e.LAST_OFFICE_WORKED))as "Pendata" 
  FROM dataag e') foo FROM DUAL;
SPOOL OFF;
```

i used this code for xml generate but colunms tag cuted after that particular of length so how will increase columns length or format max?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following commands for setting the page and line size

```
set linesize value;
set pagesize value;
```

You can set maximum values in the value

Answer (score 0):

why are you using dbms_xmlgen.getxml as a wrapper to an XMLconcat/element select? are you trying to aggregate this into 1 row?

i suspect its wrapping in the terminal though and not the log (as you have linesize 1000 in your sample and a col format of 60000). if its the log, can you post a sample XML output?

`xmlagg` is another approach to get it as one xml doc.

```
SELECT XMLSERIALIZE(content xmlagg(XMLConcat(XMLElement("ID", 
       e.ID),XMLElement("LAST_OFFICE_WORKED", e.LAST_OFFICE_WORKED))) indent) 
  FROM dataag e;
```

`XMLSERIALIZE` added just to pretty print.